# Laravel Eloquent Create

Tags: laravel

Hello so I've started using Laravel and it is useful and easy. For now I have a CRUD in which is working. In my AccountController@store the code is:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    Accounts::create($un);
    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Account successfully added!');
    return redirect()->route('accounts.index');
}
```

This basically adds a new account in my table. My problem is, I have a password textbox and I can't hash it since this code automatically gets every input in the form. How can I get it one by one? Like username, email and password only so I can hash the password.

Comment: don't forgot to make some validation before create an user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the input one by one and then hash the password and save it to the database. But that would require extra code.

You could also add an extra function to your Account model that will take care of this automatically.

Take a look at the example I use to create my management users.

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

use Hash;

class Management extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract {

    use Authenticatable;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'Management';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    /**
     * Automatic hash function for the password.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }

}
```

Regarding your code, you could do this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Accounts::create($request->all());
    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Account successfully added!');
    return redirect()->route('accounts.index');
}
```

Make sure to modify the example model above to your own needs!

Comment: I tried this one and getting this error Cannot use Authenticatable as Authenticatable because the name is already in use

Comment: Wait I made a mistake I think

Comment: Good luck with the rest of your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    Accounts::create([
        'username' => $input['username'],
        'password' => bcrypt($input['password']),
    ]);

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Account successfully added!');
    return redirect()->route('accounts.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `Input::all()` to get all the attributes passed in, and `Input:get('key')` to get a specific key.

So you should call:

```
$account = new Accounts;
$account->username = Input::get('username');
$account->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

//key with a default
$account->password = Input::get('age', 20);

//optional field
if (Input::has('optional')) {
    $account->optional = Input::get('optional');
}

//any other fields that account needs

$account->save()
```

Comment: {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'accounts.store')) !!} yes a POST. Will try your code now

Comment: where did you get new Account() ?

Comment: What type of object is Accounts? I assumed it was an Eloquent model.

Comment: Yes it is an eloquent. It should be new Accounts(); in your post

Comment: Yes small typo, I've corrected it. In the docs they don't place the (), so i've dropped those as well.

Comment: Why use the `Input` facade if you already have the `$request`??

Comment: Good point, I am still using laravel 4 where you wouldn't normally have the $request in a controller.